# colorear filas cuando hay una condición en java

Tags: java

clase 1

```
try {
  DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
  jtProductos.setModel(modelo);

  PreparedStatement ps = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  Conexion conn = new Conexion();
  Connection con = conn.getConexion();

  String sql="SELECT codigo, nombre, precio, cantidad FROM producto "+where;
  System.out.println(sql);
  ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
  rs = ps.executeQuery();

  ResultSetMetaData rsMd = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
  int cantidadColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();

  modelo.addColumn("Código");
  modelo.addColumn("Producto");
  modelo.addColumn("Precio");
  modelo.addColumn("Cantidad");
  modelo.addColumn("estatus");
  int[] anchos = {50, 200, 50, 50, 50};
  for (int i = 0; i < jtProductos.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    jtProductos.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(anchos[i]);
  }

  while (rs.next()) {
    Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas];
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadColumnas; i++) {
      filas[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
    }
    modelo.addRow(filas);
  }

} catch (Exception ex) {
  System.err.println(ex.toString());
}
```

buenas noches tengo el siguiente código para colorear las filas según el status que tenga, pero tengo el problema que no pinta las filas completas

clase 2

```
public class ColorearFilas extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if (table.getValueAt(row, 4).toString().equals("Observaciones")) {
      setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
      setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    return this;
  }
}
```

Queremos pintar las filas de la siguiente forma:

Verde: cuando se encuentre en observaciones
Amarillo: cuando se encuentre en aprobado
Rojo: cuando se encuentre en caducado

Comment: el problema es que no pinta las filas del color

Comment: ¿En que parte del codigo y de que manera le pones el *renderer* a `jtProductos`?

Comment: lo trate de unir y no me funciono

Comment: Asegúrate de establecer ese *renderer* de la forma: `jtProductos.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,new ColorearFilas());`